# Facing Issue with Custom Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am continuously getting the error: TestException.java:8: error: unreported exception Throwable; must be caught or declared to be thrown

> throw new ParentException().initCause(new
>   ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));

Any idea, i know some trivial thing is missing which i am not getting readily to my mind, thanks, don't take source for the face value, i am trying to just refresh my understanding.

```
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class TestException{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
            throw new ParentException().initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));
    }
    catch(ParentException | ChildException | SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{
                    Thread.sleep(10*1000);
            }
            catch(Exception et){
                    ;
            }
    }

    }
 }

  class ParentException extends Exception{

    public ParentException(){
            super("Parent Exception is called");
    }

}

 class ChildException extends Exception{

    public ChildException(){
            super("Child Exception is called");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code better so we can be more helpful

Answer (score 1):

`initCause` returns a `Throwable`.

That means you're actually throwing a `Throwable` and not a `ParentException` so the compiler is complaining that you are throwing a `Throwable` but are not catching it.

You can fix this by changing `ParentException` and `ChildException` so that they not only receive the error message but also receive the cause. You can then call the [`Exception` constructor that receives a message and a cause](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable))

Answer (score 1):

initCause() will throw **Throwable** object,  so you should catch that exception

```
    catch (Throwable e)
    {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Because `initCause` returns a `Throwable` instance :

```
public synchronized Throwable initCause(Throwable cause)
```

While catch clause is not able to catch any `Throwable` reference. You can add Throwable along with other exceptions.

```
try {
            throw new ParentException().initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));
        } catch (ParentException | ChildException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            } catch (Exception et) {
                ;
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

OR Just catch Throwable , if you want to catch all throwables including mentioned three exceptions and all other error , exceptions that extends Throwable

```
try {
            throw new ParentException().initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `initCause(Throwable cause)` function returns an object of `Throwable` : [`public synchronized Throwable initCause(Throwable cause)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#initCause(java.lang.Throwable)) and so when you do `throw new ParentException().initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));`, you are basically doing `throw    ( new ParentException().initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException())) ) ;`, so you are doing `throw <ThrowableObject>`, hence you must catch an Exception of `Throwable`.

```
try {
    throw new ParentException().initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));
} catch (Throwable e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     try {
         Thread.sleep(10*1000);
     } catch(Exception ex) {}
```

You can fix this in multiple ways, the 2 best ways I feel are by either overloading the constructors in both `ParentException` and `ChildException` with

```
public ParentException(Throwable cause) { 
    super("Parent Exception is called", cause);
}
```

and similar version for `ChildException` and using

```
throw new ParentException(new ChildException(new SQLException()));
```

instead of `initcause()`, **or**, by doing the following instead

```
try {
    ParentException p = new ParentException();
    p.initCause(new ChildException().initCause(new SQLException()));
    throw p;
} catch (ParentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(10*1000);
    } catch(Exception ex) {}
```

Note: you need to catch only `ParentException` and no other Exception as it is the only Exception which may be thrown inside the body of `try`. Attempting to catch other Exceptions (which are not superclasses of `ParentException` will give the error that you are trying to catch an Exception that is never thrown.